# what lamp "ceiling" support to use having only a plain 5cm diameter hole

Tags: lighting, ceiling

I moved to a flat that has on the ceiling 5cm holes with no way to screw or a hook to hang up a lamp, just the cables coming out, like the pictures attached.

What type of support could I use to install a basic e27 socket without the need to drill or damage the ceiling?

build-in lamps could be an option but how to fix them?

[image: ceiling hole][image: ceiling hole]

Comment: Not sure if this needs more details or just more _focus_...

Answer (score 1):

Put a fisher (6mm is enough for a lamp fixture) with a hook next and hang the fixture to it. When you'll move out, just fill the holes with stucco, I assume you live in a 'brick and mortar' house and not in a 'US-style' "wood and glue" home.

Fisher: 
[image: Fisher]
Stucco:
[image: Stucco]

Comment: Any alternative that won't imply drilling? is there something like a T shape that could be used within the cable tubes?

Comment: @nbari You might be able to screw into the plaster through the holes in the socket.  I would poke about one of them with a very fine drill (with the power off of course), and see what is behind there.